# Laravel homestead storage link wot working

Tags: vagrant, homestead, laravel-5.7

I have ubuntu 16.4 and vagrant with laravel homestead.

firstly I created new file disk

```
    'teams_logo' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public/teams/logo'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage/teams/logo',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

then I executed

> php artisan storage:link

command inside VM. I see that my symlink was created (look at screen)

http://joxi.ru/J2b6Ov0F04gk12

now I can see my images, but there is one problem. My application does not shows them (look at screen)

http://joxi.ru/MAj38WvFjv1npr

But there is one strange thing. If I try to copy this path to image and paste it to browser address bar I see the picture (look at screen)

http://joxi.ru/52a53oGUEGg8v2.

Secondly I try to check my symlink inside ubuntu and I see that the symlink is red (look at screen)

http://joxi.ru/MAj38WvFjv1zpr

Answer (score 0):

You can try like Below

```
'teams_logo' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public/teams/logo'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/teams/logo', // or you can use "url('teams/logo')," 
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

Answer (score 0):

It should have been added http:// to APP_URL inside .env

Comment: That is the best practice to write the whole URL with Protocols.

Answer (score 0):

**Link Shell Extension**  Windows

To make the creation of symbolic links more user-friendly, you can best use the Link Shell Extension for Windows Explorer. [You download this tool from here][1]. Click Link Shell Extension and run the downloaded file. If you are using Windows 7 or 8, you must also download and install the Visual C ++ library. This is already present on Windows 10. After opening, click OK and click Install.

Select Yes to reopen the Windows Explorer. You can now right-click on a folder or file and choose Pick Link Source. That is the folder you want to link to. Then browse to the folder where the link should come and click Drop As ... and choose Symbolic Link.

You can simply remove the Symbolic Link without the original disappearing. In the Drop As menu you can also opt for a Hard Link. Such a link can only be made on the same disk and has the advantage that if, for example, you would delete D: \ Holiday photos, you can still access the photos via the hard link in C: \ Users \  \ Images \ Holiday pictures .

There are a number of things that you have to keep an eye on. Do not create symbolic links in symbolic links, do not create symbolic links to another symbolic link, and do not create a symbolic link with the same name as the folder already in the target location. The first two cause problems with, for example, virus scanners, which could therefore become stuck. But if you stick to this then you do not have to worry about anything else.

Source: https://pcmweb.nl/artikelen/windows-10/werken-met-symbolic-links-in-windows-10/?API_COOKIE_REDIRECTED=True

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I searched a lot online and I didn't find any solution, but I solved this, just I used `Storage::url()` instead of `asset()`.

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

That's it.